# Unicode character ſ is matched as itself and as 's.'

Tags: vim, utf-8, utf

I just tried to clean up an old German text containing the character `'ſ'` (U+017F). I wanted to replace it with `'s'`, but when I used `:%s/ſ/s/g` not only that character got replaced but also all occurrences of `'s'` followed by an arbitrary character, as if I had used the command `:%s/s./s/g`.

As an example, the text:

> Die Gleichheit **) fordert das Nachdenken heraus durch Fragen, die ſich daran knüpfen und nicht ganz leicht zu beantworten ſind.

will be replaced by my command with:

> Die Gleichheit **) fordert dasNachdenken herausdurch Fragen, die sich daran knüpfen und nicht ganz leicht zu beantworten sind.

I assume it might have something to do with the fact that `'ſ'` is represented in UTF-8 as a **sequence of two bytes** (`0xC5 0xBF`). Isn't that a bug? If not, is there a way to just replace `'ſ'` and not also `'s'`?

I am using `fileencoding=utf-8` and:

```
> vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.1 (2024 Jan 02)
Included patches: 1-151
> echo $LANG
de_DE.UTF-8
```

Here is a screenshot with `:set hlsearch`:

[image: Search highlighting reveals the matching]

---

**UPDATE**: I got hold of an installation of vim version 8.0 patches up to 586 on Windows 10, exhibiting the same behavior with both my and the `\%u` versions of the command.

Comment: I'm somewhat baffled by this file. Yes, there's different styles of 's' in old German script. But they're *different representations of the same letter*. To get cute effects like this, you'd rather use a font with different glyphs for 's' and use them when e.g. creating a PDF. Using select features of German script in a text set in Latin is inconsistent at best.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the observed behavior should be considered a bug or not but I certainly wouldn't expect it.

In general, searching/substituting characters outside of ASCII or perhaps Latin 1 or 2 is best done with the notations described under `:help /\%u`. In this case, I would use this notation:

```
:[range]s/\%u017F/s/g
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but using `:%s/\%u017F/s/g` does exactly the same here as the original command.

Comment: [Not here](https://i.imgur.com/AF052a4.png). Bug? Locale problem?

Comment: Hm, that's weird. And even weirder: I tried a few other locales like en_{US,GB}.UTF-8. Mostly the same result but occasionally I get a core dump. But not consistently. I think it's the first time that I see vim crashing. I try to add a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot and assuming that you also have `hlsearch` switched on I get the impression that in your case '\%u017F' also matches the character 's' (without the following character) but only at the beginning of a word. (The 's' in 'heraus' is not highlighted). Since those 's' get replaced by 's' it doesn't matter. But why are they matched at all?

Comment: No, in my screenshot, the only things that are highlighted are the two replacement `s`, right were the two matched `ſ` are. It works perfectly fine on my end but I still have `9.1.0`. You may have found a regression introduced in the mean time.

Comment: To add to the weirdness, on Vim 9.0 (compiled from scratch on Debian, `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`), `:%s/ſ/s/g` is broken but `:%s/\%u017F/s/g` works. I get the same on gVim 9.1.0 (Windows, `LANG=DE`). On Vim 9.1.1-151 (distributed by Arch, `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`), both commands work flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have at least partially solved the mystery. When I opened the file with `vim -u /dev/null frege_sinn_1892.txt` both versions of the command worked as expected. Using binary search in my rather large .vimrc file I found the culprit to be `set ignorecase`. However, I don't know why sometimes only the original version of the command is broken as stated by [Friedrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/796259/friedrich) in the comments to [the (first) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78214442). Anyway even with `:set ignorecase` a single character shouldn't be matched to two characters. So I consider it a bug.

Comment: You should head off to the issue tracker, then.

Comment: Yepp, I had `:set ignorecase` set. I tried again with `:set noignorecase` and found the command works in all my Vims.

Comment: @romainl will do